# CS50 Speller (PSET 5) not loading dictionary

Tags: c, dictionary, cs50

I am working through the CS50 Speller problem and facing a problem that when running the program it returns an error of "Could not unload dictionaries/large."

I have looked at other people's solutions and can't for the life of me identify what is going wrong in my program. I am thinking it is in the has function, but have seen this has function in other people's working programs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of words in dictionary
int word_count = 0;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int n = hash(word);

    node *cursor = table[n];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor -> word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        cursor = cursor -> next;

    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// Function credit to delipity(staff) on CS50 reddit page
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
         hash_value = (hash_value << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    return hash_value % N; //N is size of hashtable

}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary and check for memory issue
    // Open dictionary file and create word array
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Check for memory issue with dict
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Dictionary is null\n");
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    // Read string 1 word at a time
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(n -> word, word);
        word_count++;

        // Index word using hash function
        int dict_index = hash(word);

        // Insert into hash table if already empty
        if (table[dict_index] == NULL)
        {
            n -> next = NULL;
        }
        // Insert work as new node if not empyty
        else
        {
            n -> next = table[dict_index];
        }

        table[dict_index] = n;

    }

    // Close dictionary file
    fclose(dict);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        node *cursor = table[i];
        node *tmp = cursor;

        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor -> next;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = cursor;

        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: To get help you would need to provide more context of what you're trying to achieve and how. Specifically, you'd need to include or reference the code that is the source of the error. In this case (as a casual [search](https://github.com/search?q=Could+not+unload+dictionaries%2Flarge.&type=Code) over GitHub suggests) the problem is likely `unload` function that always returns `false`, which is interpreted by the code that uses it as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        node *cursor = table[i];

        while (cursor)
        {
            node *temp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Try this instead for the unload function

Comment: it was the return false statement. Thank you!